# Необязательный аргумент в функции

Tags: c++, python

Буквально недавно пересел с игры python на с++, пока все нормально, но никак не могу понять, как мне сделать так чтобы, если аргумент в функцию не передавали, он имел "Никакой" тип, как None в python.
Пример: есть класс Dog с конструктором

```
class Dog
{
public:
    std::string name;
    std::string color;
    std::vector<Dog> parents;

    Dog(std::string name, std::string color, std::vector<Dog> parents){
        this -> name = name;
        this -> color = color;
        this -> parents = parents;
    };
}
```

Если у Dog'a нет "родителей" я бы в python просто присвоил стандартное значение parents = None (спасибо динамической типизации)
Пример на python:

```
class Dog:
def __init__(self, name, color, parents = None):
    self.name = name
    self.color = color
    self.parents = parents
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока писал вопрос, понял как это можно сделать, лол. 
Всего лишь написать

```
Dog(std::string name, std::string color, std::vector<Dog> parents = {});
```

т.е присвоить пустой вектор по умолчанию, но теперь, если будете обращаться к вектору parents, а точнее к тому, что в нем находится, нужно проверять, пустой ли вектор или нет иначе можно случайно обратиться к несуществующим "родителям"

Comment: мне просто интересно: а как вы обратитесь к несуществующим родителям если вектор пуст? Как вы вообще собрались обращаться к родителям?

Comment: Предполагаю, что проходить по всему вектору циклом и доставать родителей, если вектор пуст, то и общаться будет не к кому

Comment: так если вектор пуст, то и количество итераций будет равно 0. Так что как вы обратитесь к несуществующим родителям при пустом векторе? Когда у вас даже и цикл не начнется

Comment: Я знаю об этом. Кто сказал, что мне надо обращаться всегда к родителям, если их нет, то и ладно, значит так задумано, что конкретная собака не имеет родителей, ведь именно я передаю в класс аргументы.

Comment: так вы сами и написали: "нужно проверять, пустой ли вектор или нет иначе можно случайно обратиться к несуществующим "родителям"

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если у собачки либо 0, либо 2 родителя, то пустой массив нормально. Если надо все-таки сделать отдельные поля для папы-мамы, то "в качестве None" применяется `std::optional`.

З.Ы. В C++ для инициализации членов класса в конструкторе обычно используют список инициализации, т.е. `: ПолеКласса1(Параметр1), ПолеКласса2(Параметр2)`, который идет между круглой скобкой объявления конструктора и фигурной скобкой. Так что часто в самом конструкторе остаются только "пустые" фигурные скобки.